# Литература по delphi+asm

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Привет всем. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, адекватную литературу по *дельфийскому* ассемблеру.

Делаю первые шаги, понял, что сишные и родные ассемблерные мануалы не очень в тему приходятся (начал путаться в регистрах и командах), примеры на delphisources.ru осилил, но они слишком общие. Уровень знаний - скажем так, хороший в делфи (многопоточные приложения с сетями, графикой и т.д.), и очень начальный в асм (последнее - сложение динамических **array of short**, то есть сложный анализ и, боже упаси, устройства совсем не знаю).

Хотелось бы "практическое пособие по освоению" с кучей примеров и базовой теорией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оригинальное наменование 
"по дельфийскому ассемблеру" ))

Вот довольно хорошая книга
http://www.delphiexpert.ru/view_download.php?id=7
по Использованию ассемблера в Дельфи

Comment: Блин, казалось, народу больше должно быть. Почувствовал себя вымирающим видом, а вам спасибо)

Comment: @Vahan Av, а что за книжка то там была?